# Jquery selector not selecting value

Tags: jquery

The following is my table and I am trying to select elements from within the table

```
<table id="DetailsGridViewDiv_Header" style="border: 1px solid;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
            <th>E</th>
            <th>F</th>
            <th>G</th>
            <th>H</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is how I am trying to extract the values from the table:

```
alert($("#DetailsGridViewDiv_Header > th:nth-child(3)").text());
```

It doesn't return any letter

Comment: Lol, @Rory, what was that in the first edit :D

Comment: @nicael damn, I thought I'd got away with it :D I had another question I edited in my clipboard and accidentally pasted it in

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you're using the direct descendant selector (`>`) and the `th` is not a direct descendant of the `#DetailsGridViewDiv_Header`. Remove that operator and it will work fine:

```
alert($("#DetailsGridViewDiv_Header th:nth-child(3)").text());
```

If you want to keep the descendant selector, you will need to follow the descendant elements in order:

```
alert($("#DetailsGridViewDiv_Header > tbody > tr > th:nth-child(3)").text());
```

Answer (score 1):

`th` not a direct descendant of the table with id `DetailsGridViewDiv_Header`, so should be:

```
$("#DetailsGridViewDiv_Header th:nth-child(3)").text()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you select something in jQuery it returns an array, so it may make more sense to use the eq() function to select the jQuery object (thanks, Rory!):

```
var $thArray = $("#DetailsGridViewDiv_Header").find("th");
alert($thArray.eq(2).text());
```

Comment: Note that this will give you an error - you're calling `text()` on a DOMElement, not a jQuery object.

Comment: No, find() returns a jQuery object.

Comment: That's right, but accessing it by index (`$thArray[2]`) returns a DOMElement.

Comment: No problem. Just FYI, `eq()` is probably a nicer way of doing it as that will get you back a jQuery object.